# Output issue for console.log('You said ${reply}');

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

Below file is vanilla.js, text editor is ATOM and running on nodejs using terminal. Code snippet is below:

```
'use strict';
const Readline = require('readline');
const rl = Readline.createInterface({
  input:process.stdin,
  output:process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.setPrompt('> ');
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', reply => {
  console.log('You said ${reply}');
});
```

After user inputs Hi, the output is You said ${reply}

```
$ node app.js
> hi
You said ${reply}
```

Wherein it should be You said hi
Presently am using Python v8.9.1

Am I missing out in code or any dependencies required. See [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7nia.jpg) attached.

Regards,
Nirmal

Answer (score 4):

[You need to use backticks `` ` `` in order to use template strings.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) You would need to change this line in your code:

```
console.log('You said ${reply}');
```

to

```
console.log(`You said ${reply}`);
```

Also check out [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nL3k0ez8/)

Answer (score 0):

> Please use backtick `` instead of string literal

```
    'use strict';
    const Readline = require('readline');
    const rl = Readline.createInterface({
      input:process.stdin,
      output:process.stdout,
      terminal: false
    });

rl.setPrompt('> ');
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', reply => {
  console.log(`You said ${reply}`);
});
```